# How to delete contentView from UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to do a CollectionView practice by following a step by step guide, and I got problem at runtime, the picture below is the correct one, but mine is different, I don't know how to remove that Content View from a Collection View Cell, can anyone help? thanks

[this is my document structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POFZf.jpg)

[the correct document structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbaxs.jpg)

Comment: You should have one. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcell/1620133-contentview It should be added nether less.

Comment: thanks Larme, I just don't need it, I want to remove that contentView from the cell

Comment: "I just don't need it", why? That's how it SHOULD be. Did you read the documentation of it, what is does?

Comment: @Danny the `ContentView` is the default view of `CollectionView` Cell, and all the subviews added to the `CollectionView` Cell will be a part of this `ContentView`, you cannot remove that `ContentView`.

Comment: I guess op may read some old tutorials, in which time there is no `ContentView` yet.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the content view and make a transparent background for it, then setup your layout above content view